# Erro no update selectOneRadio

Tags: java-ee, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Estou tentando atualizar o campo de valor e percentual da pagina em desenvolvimento. Quando coloco no ajax a opção:`update=":formDlgSolicitacao:idPercentual :formDlgSolicitacao:idValor"` ele não atualiza o campo, quando insiro `update="@form"` ele é atualizado entretanto apaga o que eu tinha selecionado em aluno.

o código desse radio é esse:

```
<p:selectOneRadio value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.opcaoValor}">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Percentual" itemValue="3" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Valor" itemValue="4" />
                            <p:ajax event="change"
                                listener="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.habilitarFiltrosValor()}"
                                update=":formDlgSolicitacao:idPercentual :formDlgSolicitacao:idValor"
                                process="@this" />      
</p:selectOneRadio>
                        <pe:inputNumber id="idPercentual" size="15"
                            value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.bolsaEstudo.valor}"
                            rendered="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.habilitaFiltroPercentual}"
                            decimalPlaces="0" symbol="%" symbolPosition="s" />

                        <pe:inputNumber id="idValor" size="15"
                            value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.bolsaEstudo.valor}"
                            rendered="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.habilitaFiltroValor}"
                            symbol="R$" />
```

O método de validar a opção é essa:

```
public void habilitarFiltrosValor() {

    if (opcaoValor == 3) {
        habilitaFiltroPercentual = Boolean.TRUE;
        habilitaFiltroValor = Boolean.FALSE;
    }
    if (opcaoValor == 4) {
        habilitaFiltroPercentual = Boolean.FALSE;
        habilitaFiltroValor = Boolean.TRUE;
    }

}
```

Esse selectOneRadio está em um Dialog.

Código do Dialog

```
<p:dialog closeOnEscape="true"
            header="Solicitação de Bolsa de Estudo" widgetVar="dlgBolsa"
            footer="SIGAAC - Sistema de Gerenciamento de Atividades Acadêmicas"
            showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip" width="650" modal="true"
            appendTo="@(body)">
            <h:form id="formDlgSolicitacao">

                <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <h:panelGrid>
                        <h:outputText value="Nº Processo" />
                        <p:inputMask size="10"
                            value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.bolsaEstudo.id}"
                            readonly="true" />
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <h:panelGrid>
                        <h:outputText value="Data/Hora" />
                        <p:inputText id="txtData" readonly="true"
                            value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.data}">
                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" timeZone="GMT-3" />
                        </p:inputText>
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <h:panelGrid>
                        <h:outputText value="Status" />
                        <p:inputText id="txtStatus" value="Em digitação" readonly="true" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:panelGrid>

                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:panelGrid>
                        <h:outputText value="ID Curso" />
                        <p:inputMask size="10" id="idDlgCurso" readonly="true"
                            value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.curso.id}" mask="9?99999">
                            <p:ajax
                                update=":formDlgSolicitacao:txtDlgCurso :formDlgSolicitacao:idDlgCurso :growl"
                                process="@this"
                                listener="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.carregarCurso()}"
                                event="change" />
                        </p:inputMask>
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <h:panelGrid>
                        <h:outputText value="Nome do Curso" />
                        <p:inputText size="60" id="txtDlgCurso" readonly="true"
                            value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.curso.nome}" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                        <h:outputText value="ID Etapa" />
                        <p:inputMask mask="9?99999" id="idEtapa" size="10"
                            value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.idEtapa}">
                            <p:ajax event="change"
                                update=":formDlgSolicitacao:idEtapa :formDlgSolicitacao:txtEtapa"
                                process="@this"
                                listener="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.carregarEtapa()}" />
                        </p:inputMask>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                        <h:outputText value="Descrição Etapa" />
                        <p:inputText size="30" id="txtEtapa" readonly="true"
                            value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.etapa.etapa}  #{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.etapa.ofertaTurma.ofertaCurso.curso.perIntegralizacao.descricao}" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:panelGrid>
                        <h:outputText value=" " />
                        <h:outputText value=" " />
                        <h:outputText value=" " />
                        <h:outputText value=" " />
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search"
                            onclick="PF('dlgEtapa').show()" update=":formEtapa"
                            process="@this" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:panelGrid>

                <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <h:panelGrid>
                        <p:selectOneRadio value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.opcaoAluno}">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="CPF" itemValue="1" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="ID" itemValue="2" />
                            <p:ajax event="change"
                                listener="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.habilitarFiltrosAluno()}"
                                update=":formDlgSolicitacao:cpfAluno :formDlgSolicitacao:idAluno"
                                process="@this" />
                        </p:selectOneRadio>

                        <p:inputMask size="15" id="cpfAluno" mask="999.999.999-99"
                            rendered="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.habilitarFiltroCpf}"
                            value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.cpfAluno}">
                            <p:ajax
                                update=":formDlgSolicitacao:cpfAluno :formDlgSolicitacao:txtNomeAluno :growl"
                                listener="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.carregarAlunoCPF()}"
                                event="change" process="@form" />
                        </p:inputMask>
                        <p:inputMask size="15" id="idAluno" mask="9?99999"
                            rendered="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.habilitarFiltroID}"
                            value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.idAluno}">
                            <p:ajax
                                update=":formDlgSolicitacao:idAluno :formDlgSolicitacao:txtNomeAluno :growl"
                                process="@this"
                                listener="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.carregarAlunoID()}"
                                event="change" />
                        </p:inputMask>
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <h:panelGrid>
                        <h:outputText value=" " />
                        <h:outputText value=" " />
                        <h:outputText value=" " />
                        <h:outputText value=" " />
                        <h:outputText value="Nome do Aluno" />
                        <p:inputText size="60" id="txtNomeAluno"
                            value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.alunoCurso.aluno.pessoa.nome}" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:panelGrid>
                        <h:outputText value=" " />
                        <h:outputText value=" " />
                        <h:outputText value=" " />
                        <h:outputText value=" " />
                        <h:outputText value=" " />
                        <h:outputText value=" " />
                        <h:outputText value=" " />
                        <h:outputText value=" " />
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search"
                            onclick="PF('dlgAluno').show()" update=":formAluno:tblAluno"
                            process="@this" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:panelGrid>

                <fieldset class="fieldSetBorder">
                    <legend>
                        <strong>Bolsa</strong>
                    </legend>

                    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                        <h:panelGrid>
                            <h:outputText value="ID Tipo" />
                            <p:inputMask size="10" id="idBolsa" mask="9?99999"
                                style="height:10px" value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.idBolsa}"
                                tabindex="1" readonly="true">
                                <p:ajax
                                    update=":formDlgSolicitacao:idBolsa :formDlgSolicitacao:txtBolsa :growl"
                                    event="change"
                                    listener="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.carregarTipoBolsa()}" />

                            </p:inputMask>

                        </h:panelGrid>

                        <h:panelGrid>
                            <h:outputText value="Descrição" />
                            <p:inputText size="60" id="txtBolsa" readonly="true"
                                value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.tipoBolsaEstudo.descricao}" />
                        </h:panelGrid>

                        <h:panelGrid>
                            <h:outputText value=" " />
                            <h:outputText value=" " />
                            <h:outputText value=" " />
                            <h:outputText value=" " />
                            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search"
                                onclick="PF('dlgTipoBolsa').show()" update=":formTipoBolsas"
                                process="@this" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                        <h:panelGrid>
                            <h:outputText value="Cobertura" />

                            <p:inputText size="15" id="idCoberturaInicio" readonly="true"
                                value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.tipoBolsaEstudo.faixaIniCobertura}" />
                        </h:panelGrid>

                        <h:panelGrid>
                            <h:outputText value=" " />
                            <h:outputText value=" " />
                            <h:outputText value=" " />
                            <h:outputText value=" " />
                            <h:outputText value="até" />
                        </h:panelGrid>

                        <h:panelGrid>
                            <h:outputText value=" " />
                            <h:outputText value=" " />
                            <h:outputText value=" " />
                            <h:outputText value=" " />
                            <p:inputText size="15" id="idCoberturaFim" readonly="true"
                                value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.tipoBolsaEstudo.faixaFimCobertura}" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset class="fieldSetBorder">
                    <legend>
                        <strong>Solicitação</strong>
                    </legend>

                    <h:panelGrid>
                        <p:selectOneRadio value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.opcaoValor}">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Percentual" itemValue="3" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Valor" itemValue="4" />
                            <p:ajax event="change"
                                listener="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.habilitarFiltrosValor()}"
                                update=":formDlgSolicitacao:idPercentual :formDlgSolicitacao:idValor"
                                process="@this" />
                        </p:selectOneRadio>
                        <pe:inputNumber id="idPercentual" size="15"
                            value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.bolsaEstudo.valor}"
                            rendered="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.habilitaFiltroPercentual}"
                            decimalPlaces="0" symbol="%" symbolPosition="s" />

                        <pe:inputNumber id="idValor" size="15"
                            value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.bolsaEstudo.valor}"
                            rendered="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.habilitaFiltroValor}"
                            symbol="R$" />
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                        <h:panelGrid>
                            <h:outputText value="Período Inicial" />

                            <p:calendar locale="pt"
                                value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.bolsaEstudo.dtInicioVigencia}" />
                        </h:panelGrid>

                        <h:panelGrid>
                            <h:outputText value=" " />
                            <h:outputText value=" " />
                            <h:outputText value=" " />
                            <h:outputText value=" " />
                            <h:outputText value="até" />
                        </h:panelGrid>

                        <h:panelGrid>
                            <h:outputText value="Período Final" />

                            <p:calendar locale="pt"
                                value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.bolsaEstudo.dtFinalVigencia}" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="fieldSetBorder">
                    <legend>
                        <strong>Incidência</strong>
                    </legend>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                        <p:inputMask id="idIncidencia" mask="9?99999" size="10"
                            value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.idIncidencia}">

                            <p:ajax event="change"
                                listener="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.carregarIncidencia()}"
                                update=":formDlgSolicitacao:idIncidencia :formDlgSolicitacao:txtIncidencia :growl"
                                process="@this" />
                        </p:inputMask>

                        <p:inputText size="60" id="txtIncidencia"
                            value="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.incidencia.descricao}" />

                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search"
                            update=":formIncidencia:tblIncidencia" process="@this"
                            onclick="PF('dlgIncidencia').show()" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </fieldset>
                <div align="center">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <p:commandButton value="Gravar"
                            action="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.solicitar()}"
                            onclick="PF('dlgBolsa').hide()" icon="ui-icon-disk"
                            process="@this" />

                        <p:commandButton value="Limpar" onclick="PF('dlgBolsa').hide()"
                            icon="ui-icon-trash"
                            action="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.limpar()}"
                            update=":formSolicitacao:txtCurso :formSolicitacao:idCurso :formSolicitacao
                            :formSolicitacao:tabView01 :formSolicitacao:txtPerLetivo :formSolicitacao:idPerLetivo"
                            process="@this" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </div>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
```

Comment: Alguém para me ajudar??

Comment: qual o id do dialog? o form está fora ou dentro dele?

Comment: formDlgSolicitacao é o id do Dialog e ele esta dentro do dialog

Comment: tem como postar a estrutura do seu dialog?

Comment: tem sim... ele está um pouco gigante mas eu posto kk

Comment: Já está postada.

Comment: tenta colocar um id nesse p:dialog e dar um update começando por ele, já volto 5 minutinhos

Comment: Cara ele ainda continua da mesma forma.... ele não apaga valores entretanto não muda o campo que tem uma mascara de percentual para valor.

Comment: tenta colocar um id no  `<h:panelGrid>` que fica o `<pe:inputNumber>` depois da um `update="formDlgSolicitacao:pnlGrid:idPercentual"`

Comment: Você está tentando mostrar/esconder os `inputNumber` ao mudar a opção do `selectOneMenu`?

Comment: É exatamente isso. Para que a pessoas digite o desconto da bolsa escolar em porcentagem ou em valor.

Comment: Techies esse de colocar id no PanelGrid eu ja havia testado nada foi alterado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se um componente não estiver renderizado na página, por mais que seu atributo `rendered` mude o valor para `true`, você não vai conseguir desenhá-lo apenas fazendo o `update` utilizando seu ID. Você deve atualizar o 'pai' desse componente para atingir tal objetivo.

Minha sugestão é:

Envelope os inputs em um `<p:panel id="painel">`

E então, no update do `<p:ajax>` do `<p:selectOneRadio>` coloque o ID do novo panel: `update=":formDlgSolicitacao:painel"`

Comment: Mesmo fazendo dessa forma não muda o campo para inserir.

Comment: O actionListener está sendo chamado? Está bem difícil entender seu objetivo. Você também colocou muito código na pergunta...

Comment: Está sim ele entra realiza tudo normal... O campo de percentual vem por padrão... quando seleciono valo no radio ele deveria atualizar para o campo de valor monetario que eu coloquei lá... mas ele simplesmente não muda o campo, não atualiza.

Comment: Então no seu `public void habilitarFiltrosValor()` não deveria setar o valor de `#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.bolsaEstudo.valor}` ?. Por que não vi em nenhum lugar essa atribuição. Algo como `this.bolsaEstudo.valor = this.opcaovalor;`

Comment: Esse valor vai ser inserido a mão, na hora em que o aluno for realizar a matricula e solicitar bolsa de estudos.

Answer (score 0):

Parece-me que o seu problema está nesta condição

```
rendered="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.habilitaFiltroValor}"
```

ou para ser mais exato neste método

```
public void habilitarFiltrosValor() {

    if (opcaoValor == 3) {
        habilitaFiltroPercentual = Boolean.TRUE;
        habilitaFiltroValor = Boolean.FALSE;
    }
    if (opcaoValor == 4) {
        habilitaFiltroPercentual = Boolean.FALSE;
        habilitaFiltroValor = Boolean.TRUE;
    }

}
```

Você precisar retornar um valor booleano no método acima para que o mesmo seja utilizado no atributo **rendered** do componente usado no dialog.

Comment: Quando acrescento a condição rendered="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.habilitaFiltroValor}" ele ira renderizar quando o  habilitaFiltroValor for "true".

O rendered="#{solicitacaoBolsasBacking.habilitaFiltroValor}" só será renderizado quando for true então não preciso colocar mais condiçoes ai. Certo??

Comment: @MarcosRaiAlvesdaCunha, perdão. Não tinha percebido. Você tem um atributo chamado habilitaFiltroValor e um método chamado habilitarFiltrosValor. O rendered está levando em consideração o atributo booleano habilitaFiltroValor. Então a lógica do rendered está correta.